# Why is post-vaccination fever for 4CMenB so frequent?

Tags: vaccination

When considering the introduction of 4CMenB vaccine, [the Joint Committee on Vaccination and Immunisation said](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/225004/Minutes_Meningococcal_sub-committee_meeting_April_2013_-_final.pdf):

> The sub-committee noted that the clinical trials data suggest that
>   when  4CMenB vaccine is given concomitantly with other routine
>   childhood  immunisations a substantially increased frequency of
>   vaccine-induced  fevers should be expected. Vaccine-induced fever
>   rates may be similar to  those associated with whole cell pertussis
>   vaccine used in the past.

What is the likely explanation for the higher rate of fever for 4CMenB in comparison with other vaccines?